# Working with two URLs in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have to get values from two different URLs and then to merge it. I know it would much better if i'll get all of the data in one URL, but that's how i've got and i need to work with it.

I want to print out the value of `a_value`, but it's been printed out while `b` hasn't returned his value. I've read some articles of how to make the functions synchronous but still don't know how to implement it into my code, and don't know what is the best solution for my case. I'm pretty new with JavaScript and still need some help and guiding.

```
  function any_function() {
        $.ajax(
            {
                url : '/url1',
                type: "GET",
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    $("#print").html(a(data));
                }
            });
        }


    function a(data){

        x = 'any value' //`do something with data and insert to this variable`
        a_value =  x + b(`some id that extracted from data`)

        return a_value
    }


  function b(id){
    $.ajax({
                url: '/url2', 
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    b_value = c(data, id)  
                }
            });
   return b_value
  }


  function c(data, id){
        //do something with `data` and return the value
        return c_value
    }
```

Comment: using promises is the way to go https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function f() {
    var request1 = $.ajax({
        url : '/url1',
        type: 'GET'
    });
    var request2 = $.ajax({
        url: '/url2', 
        type: 'GET'
    });
    $.when(request1, request2).done(function(result1, result2){
        data1 = result1[0]
        data2 = result2[0]
        // r1 and r2 are arrays [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
        // Do stuff here with data1 and data2
        // If you want to return use a callback or a promise
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where should i find the data the has been pulled by ajax? Is it suppose to be in the variables `url1` and `url2`?

Comment: @Omri data is in result1 and result2

Comment: Thanks! I have the whole object in result1 and result2. How can i get only his data? I my ajax success `data` had only the relevant json, while in your code o have the whole object.

Comment: @Ormi result1.data and result2.data

Comment: I've tried `result1.data['result']` and got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined`. The name of the json root is `result`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've got `Uncaught ReferenceError: data1 is not defined`. On the debugger i see that `result1 = [Object, "success", Object]`.

Comment: I've submitted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241389/json-parsing-in-javascript-issue

Comment: @Ormi if you found this help full can you accept my answer

Comment: Done. Thank you so much for the help. I still have some issue with the json, but it's not related to the main question.

Comment: Can you show me how should i return a value for this function?  (callback or promise. No matter what). Now everything works fine and the function return the right value. However, nothing happen after trying to print out the return value in HTML.

Comment: @Omri jQuery Promises: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html

Comment: @Ormi Callbacks: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a synchronous-looking fashion with promises:

```
$.get(url1)
.then(function(data1){
  return $.get(url2)
})
.then(function(data2){
  return $.get(url3);
})
.then(function(data3){
  // All done
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As i said above, i don't have a vast of experience with JavaScript. Can you show me how exactly should i use my ajax call in your code? Do i just need to replace `url1` with the real url?

Comment: The requests can be done in parrallel which would be faster

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the second call in the success handler of the first one:

```
function any_function() {
    $.ajax({
            url : '/url1',
            type: "GET",
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#print").html(a(data));
                b("someId");
            }
    });
 }

 function a(data){

    x = 'any value' //`do something with data and insert to this variable`
    a_value =  x + b(`some id that extracted from data`)

    return a_value;
 }

function b(id){
  $.ajax({
            url: '/url2', 
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                b_value = c(data, id);  
                return b_value;
            }
  });
}


function c(data, id){
    //do something with `data` and return the value
    return c_value
}
```

Comment: It would be better to do both requests in parrallel

Comment: The user is asking about a way to do it synchronously, not in parallel.

Comment: The user wants to run code once both requests are done

Comment: And, if the requests happen synchronously, that can be achieved.

Comment: True, but it would be faster if they were parallel