# json parsing in JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have the following json:

```
{
"result":[
   {
     "a": 500000,
     "b": null,
     "c": 0,
     "d": 0,
     "e": 1855
  },
  {
     "a": 500001,
     "b": null,
     "c": 0,
     "d": 0,
     "e": 3770
  }
],
"host": "43252ed565f9",
"time": "Wed Mar 23 09:57:43 UTC 2016",
"status": "Ok"
}
```

I'm trying to parse it, but got a strange value of `"["`, instead each one of the keys.

```
    function f() {
              var request1 = $.ajax({
                  url: '/a', 
                  type: 'GET',
              });
              var request2 = $.ajax({
                   url : '/b',
                   type: "GET"
              });
              $.when(request1, request2).done(function(result1, result2){
                        //result1 = [Object, "success", Object]
                        json =  JSON.stringify(result1)

              for( key in json){
                    myJson = json[key] //The value is: "["

               a = myJson['a']
               b = myJson['b']
               c = myJson['c']
               d = myJson['d']
               e = myJson['e']

              }
})
          }
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: what is key in `json[key]`

Comment: Is this because of the `JSON.stringify`? How can i parse it as json?

Comment: json is always a string

Comment: refer to this question: [Parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824224/syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character)

Comment: @AmanuelBogale Not yet. I'm trying to use your code, and figure out how to extract each key and key in loop.

Comment: @Omri did you solve it now? I showed you how to do that on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to parse by `JSON.parse()` because the answer is already an object itself you can do this.

```
function f() {
              var request1 = $.ajax({
                  url: '/a', 
                  type: 'GET',
              });
              var request2 = $.ajax({
                   url : '/b',
                   type: "GET"
              });
              $.when(request1, request2).done(function(result1, result2){
                        //result1 = [Object, "success", Object]


              for( key in result1){
                    a = result1[key] //The value is: "["

              }
})
          }
```

In fact ill show a snippet:

```js
var Json = {
  "result": [{
    "a": 500000,
    "b": null,
    "c": 0,
    "d": 0,
    "e": 1855
  }, {
    "a": 500001,
    "b": null,
    "c": 0,
    "d": 0,
    "e": 3770
  }],
  "host": "43252ed565f9",
  "time": "Wed Mar 23 09:57:43 UTC 2016",
  "status": "Ok"
}

for (key in Json) {
  a = Json[key] //The value is: "["

}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = a
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

### Reason Behind This

The reason behind this is because the JSON is already an object. Therfore there is no need to JSON.parse() it or JSON.stringify() it. Simple as that! Hope this helped!

### FOR LOOP

In the for loop im looping over the objects.. And constantly rewritting the variable a. So at the end the variable a would equal "Ok", because thats the last "Object" in the JSON. Now lets say you want to keep every "Objects", then you will need a "count":

```
count=0; //GLOBAL VARIABLE.
  for ( key in result1){
    actualJSON[count]
    count++;
  }
```

Now the actualJSON Has the all of the "objects" of that JSON.

Comment: Only 'the person' would know; and there is no requirement to explain downvotes.. annoying as it may be.

Comment: But result1[1] should be statusText as documented at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/. Why you write `a = result1[key]`?

Comment: @AmanuelBogale I din't understand your `for` loop. Can you explain and add more details regarding how to extract each key and key into a parameter?

Comment: I'm referring to the last example in that page where is write: `Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]`. So he must take the first item of the array? I do not want to be right and i'm sorry if i misunderstood your code.

Comment: @AmanuelBogale I'm not sure if i understood the loop section. I got the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: actualJSON is not defined`.

Comment: Well, that's was I've finally managed to to extract the parameters: `result1[0].result[0].a`, `result1[0].result[0].b`, `result1[0].result[1].a`,  `result1[0].result[1].b`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Result1 is `[Object, "success", Object]` and not the JSON as described in final example here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/.

`result1[0]` should be the response of the ajax request and so it should be the javascript object that map the JSON of the response.

Answer (score 1):

`result1` and `result2` is already the objects, you don't need to `parse` or `stringify` it.

Just iterate it:

```
for(var key in result1){
    var a = result1[key];
    // do something with 'a'
}
```

Comment: replace json with `result`

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` returns a string.

Use:

```
var json = typeof(result1[0]) === 'string' ? JSON.parse(result1[0]) : result1[0];
```

The `[0]` is because `$.ajax()` returns the data in the first argument in `done` function.

Answer (score -1):

After reading all the comments I understood that your `result1` is an object. Hence no need to parse it, you can directly access the values. Here is a example snippet.

```js
var Json = {
  "result": [{
    "a": 500000,
    "b": null,
    "c": 0,
    "d": 0,
    "e": 1855
  }, {
    "a": 500001,
    "b": null,
    "c": 0,
    "d": 0,
    "e": 3770
  }],
  "host": "43252ed565f9",
  "time": "Wed Mar 23 09:57:43 UTC 2016",
  "status": "Ok"
}

for (key in Json) {
  a = Json[key] 
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += a + '<br/>';
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: IIRC, the returned object is *already* deserialized. Using `parse` probably results in errors about "o".

Comment: @user2864740 yes I read that the OP is getting the error in the other answers comment

Comment: @Daedalus lets remove the noise here. As well as Reddy. Lets polish up this question and anwser a bit!

Comment: @Daedalus changd my answer.

Comment: @AmanuelBogale confusing or suspecious?? There is a option called copy snippet to answer, using that I took your snippet and modified the things I wanted.

Comment: Im saying that snippet is confusing. It gives a anwser i didnt expect.